# iOS HTML5 Audio Duration showing "0"

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio

I am having an issue getting the HTML5 Audio duration to show up in iOS. Instead of showing the duration it shows "0". The issue occurs in both Chrome and Safari on iOS but it works fine in all browsers on my desktop.

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "audio/shady.mp3";
audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    $('.time span').html(readableDuration(audio.duration));
});

function readableDuration(seconds) {
    sec = Math.floor( seconds );    
    min = Math.floor( sec / 60 );
    min = min >= 10 ? min : '0' + min;    
    sec = Math.floor( sec % 60 );
    sec = sec >= 10 ? sec : '0' + sec;    
    return min + ':' + sec;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="time"><strong>Audio</strong> (<span></span>)</div>
```

I've tried a number of things and nothing seems to work. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Don't you think it would be helpful to show the code for the `readableDuration` function? There's no way we can help you if we can't even see what's going wrong.

Comment: @Doorknob Do you have any additional feedback on this now that I have added this requested script? Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been quite the thorn in my side.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what's happening. I've edited the post for formatting and to add a few more relevant tags; that'll also bump it to the front page so more people might see it. You might get help more quickly if you post a simple, self-contained example that reproduces the problem, so that users can test it themselves and make changes to it to see if it's fixed; [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a good tool to make it easier for users to test the code themselves.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the efforts. I'm sorry, I'm having trouble getting this to load with jsFiddle.